# How to exclude singular words from Solr's suggest component?

Tags: java, solr

In Solr's org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchComponent (the one we use for autosuggest), How to exclude singualr words ?

For example if the response of the suggestions contains "laptop" and "laptops", I want to exclude/remove "laptop".

I wouldn't like to use a hardcoded solution since Solr could contains a lot of these singular/plurals.

Comment: you can apply stemming to the field you are using for autosuggest. However, Stemming would remove the plural forms which is a more valid suggestion then plural or any other form.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong but with stemming, I'm going to lose the "plural" form of the words.

Comment: Yes, you are going to loose them.